# duvida firebase com ionic (ion-select)

Tags: ionic, firebase, typescript

Tenho uma aplicação, e quero saber como faço para inserir informações no database do firebase e depois colocar esses dados dentro de um *ion-select*, minha aplicação usa um *select* de profissoes como: "mecanico", "pedreiro", "professor" e etc, e quero que isso fique dentro de um *ion-option* do *ion-select*, porém não sei como fazer. No meu codigo fiz assim:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="profissoes1" okText="Salvar" cancelText="Cancelar">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let items of items">{{items}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

e quero uma dica de como usar no typescript, para pegar as profissões do firebase ficarem no lugar do {{items}}, e como inserir as profissoes no firebase tambem

Answer (score 1):

Neste [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uP_v6RhnP5U&list=PLHlHvK2lnJnccBL9grcoRxv8CsLa9Q_4q) há um tutorial de firebase, com certeza irá te ajudar.

Este [outro link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/) refere-se a documentação de ion-select.

A vantagem de se usar FireBase é que você não precisa codificar o back-end. Entretanto, antes de fazer as requisições, você tem que se lembrar de alterar a autorização default para liberar essas requisições para outros usuários.
Recebido o resultado dessa requisição, o que você tem que fazer é armazená-lo numa variável e fazer uma iteração (repetição) com o *NgFor e passar o valor e nome mostrado, exemplo:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="data.person" multiple>
  <ion-option *ngFor="let name of namesList" [value] = "name.firstName" [checked]="false">{{name.firstName}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Neste exemplo, entende-se que você armazenou o resultado da requisição na variável **namesList** e para cada item, você chama de "name", e para acessar os atributos deste objeto, usa o nome do objeto (name) seguido do nome do atributo (firstName), ficando 'name.firstName'

Comment: é que eu to realmente perdido no ion-select, e no firebase eu so uso o push e pego os dados pela referencia, porém nessa situação, eu quero que as informações sejam inseridas manualmente no banco e fique dentro do ion-option

Comment: Certo, para adicionar dado manualmente no seu banco de dados Firebase, veja [este link](http://mariechatfield.com/tutorials/firebase/step2.html).
Para popular os seus ion-options com os dados vindos do banco, você tem que montar um serviço que faça uma requisição trazendo os dados dessa rota (/usuarios, por exemplo), e retornar essa promise para a sua página, e por fim, atribuir essa promise no atributo que vai estar no ng-model